# Powershell send-mailmessage to 2 recipients returns "the server response was 4.5.3 too many recipients"

Tags: powershell, smtp, exchange-server

I have a PowerShell script that runs a report on an SQL database and attaches the report to an email sent using `send-mailmessage`.

My syntax is `send-mailmessage -to user1@domain.com.au -cc user2@domain.com.au -subject "PE matter report (Since 1 July 2015)" -bodyashtml -body $body -Attachments "C:\scripts-and-reports\New PE matters since 01 July 2015.xlsx" -from databaseserver@domain.com.au -Priority high -Verbose  -SmtpServer domain-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com`.

It returns an error

> send-mailmessage : Insufficient system storage. The server response
>   was: 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090)
>
> [AM1FFO11FD023.protection.gbl]

If I remove the Cc from the script, the message sends OK and is received OK.
But I kind of need the Cc in there and if possible, a Bcc as well.

I have added the server's WAN IP to my domain's SPF record (and it tests OK), I have added the URL to Office365's ExchangeOnline Connection Filter Allowed list, and I have even added a transport rule checking the IP which sets SCL to -1 and bypasses clutter.

I just can't figure this out.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are any of the addresses you're using distribution lists?  Has your administrator set any kind of email throttling?

Comment: No they're not.  One is my address, the other is the office manager's address.  
I'm the email administrator - there is no throttling apart from the MS Office365 imposed limits.

Comment: I also am having the issue.  I also am connecting to an MX level server.  Looks like MX only allows one recipient at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a possibilities that could be tried than a definite answer.

1. A question first: Are the user1@domain.com.au and/or user2@domain.com.au distribution lists?  If yes, try it with single user addresses.
2. Maybe you are hitting somehow the throttling limit - which you can find [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#summary).  To quote the support page - the throttling limit for *STMP client submission*.   The limit is:

> 10,000 recipients per day. 30 messages per minute

(As Bacon Bits has written you may have some internal limit on top of this one)
You have to be bellow this limit.  You are probably hitting the limit with the `-cc`.

3. To enclose the mail address/lists with double quotes
   `send-mailmessage -to "user1@domain.com.au" -cc "user2@domain.com.au" ...`
4. Does it work for with `-bcc` excluding  the `-cc`?
5. Is `-cc` optional or always filled?

Comment: 1. no; 2. it's two actual mailboxes on the same domain/o365 tenancy using the direct send method; 3. tried this, made no difference; 4. no, not even if I use `-to @('user1@domain.com.au','user2@domain.com.au')`; 5. It's optional - if I ONLY use `-to`, the email sends fine.

Note that I am using our O365 MX's points to address as the SMTP with no authentication.  If I use a different SMTP (the SMTP of the ISP for example) `-cc` and `-bcc` work OK.  But this won't work for our Azure hosted servers.

Comment: @ReeceDodds: so the issue is not with the powershell's `send-message` but the Azure hosted SMTP, isn't that so?  Maybe your message is considered a SPAM somehow?

Comment: @ReeceDodds: Check this list if it maybe one of these? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/hotmail-email/how-do-i-interpret-the-delivery-failure-message/2f1bf9c0-8b03-4f8f-aacc-5f6ba60a73f3 .  From the message it would appear that your mailbox from which you are sending it maybe at its limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a workaround...

I've switched to using the Office365 SMTP server with authentication and SSL.

The new command is:-

`$login = "mailboxwithsendaspermission@domain.com.au"`

`$password = "abovemailboxpassword" | Convertto-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

`$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Pscredential -Argumentlist $login,$password`

`send-mailmessage -to user1@domain.com.au -cc user2@domain.com.au -subject "PE matter report (Since 1 July 2015)" -bodyashtml -body $body -Attachments "C:\scripts-and-reports\New PE matters since 01 July 2015.xlsx" -from databaseserver@domain.com.au -Priority high -Verbose -UseSsl -Port 587 -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Credential $credentials`

I think this is less secure because the password is stored in plain text, but all of the servers are sitting behind a firewall and aren't used by anyone else.

I hadn't thought of doing it this way - but at least it is working for `-to`, `-cc` and `-bcc` all at the same time.